# TexMaker 5.0.4 (Mac) generates wrong output

Tags: macros, texmaker

I just want to print `\titleStringGerman` "*My Title*" defined in `__MyStyle.sty`

**__MyStyle.sty**

```
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=mysty@,prefix=mysty@}
\DeclareStringOption{titleStringGerman}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions{mysty@}
\newcommand{\titleStringGerman}{\mysty@titleStringGerman}
\endinput
```

**Example.tex**

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[titleStringGerman={My Title}]{__TexMaker/__MyStyle}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\titleStringGerman
\end{document}
```

**Variant 1**

With TexMaker 5.0.4 (Mac) and TexLive 2020 the generated .pdf doesn't show "*My Title*" text.
[image: TexMaker]

**Variant 2**

With Bitbucket Pipeline it works like expected.

```
image: dme26/latex-builder:latest
pipelines:
 default:
   - step:
      script:
       - pdflatex -jobname=Test Example.tex;
       - pdflatex -jobname=Test Example.tex;
       - ls
       - curl -X POST "https://${BB_AUTH_STRING}@api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"Example.pdf"
```

[image: Bitbucket]

How can that be? I think it's a very minimalistic example... where can be the differences?

**EDIT 1:**

**Example.log**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.12.20)  21 DEC 2020 16:26
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Example.tex
(./Example.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
Package: scrlfile-hook 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforeFile with sig. 'm' on line 61.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterFile with sig. 'm' on line 65.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforeClass with sig. 'm' on line 69.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforePackage with sig. 'm' on line 73.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterAtEndOfClass with sig. 'smo+m' on line 83.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterAtEndOfPackage with sig. 'smo+m' on line
(LaTeX3)     93.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \scrlfile@AfterClass with sig. 'smo+m' on line
(LaTeX3)     173.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterClass with sig. '' on line 174.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \scrlfile@AfterPackage with sig. 'smo+m' on line
(LaTeX3)     191.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterPackage with sig. '' on line 192.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ReplaceInput with sig. '' on line 193.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ReplaceClass with sig. 'mm' on line 196.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ReplacePackage with sig. 'mm' on line 199.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnReplaceInput with sig. '' on line 200.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnReplaceClass with sig. 'm' on line 203.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnReplacePackage with sig. 'mm' on line 206.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \PreventPackageFromLoading with sig. 's+om' on
(LaTeX3)     line 234.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \StorePreventPackageFromLoading with sig. 'm' on
(LaTeX3)     line 242.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ResetPreventPackageFromLoading with sig. '' on
(LaTeX3)     line 247.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnPreventPackageFromLoading with sig. 'sm' on
(LaTeX3)     line 261.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforeClosingMainAux with sig. 'om' on line
(LaTeX3)     274.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterReadingMainAux with sig. 'om' on line 287.

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \protected@immediate@write with sig. 'm+m+m' on
(LaTeX3)     line 298.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty
Package: scrlogo 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (logo)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box47
)
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `toc' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 137.
Class scrbook Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrbook)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 2437
.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip48
\ta@div=\count177
\ta@hblk=\skip49
\ta@vblk=\skip50
\ta@temp=\skip51
\footheight=\skip52
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 47.2316pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = -12.5192pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1740.
)
\c@part=\count178
\c@chapter=\count179
\c@section=\count180
\c@subsection=\count181
\c@subsubsection=\count182
\c@paragraph=\count183
\c@subparagraph=\count184
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\chapter on input line 5625.
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\section on input line 5636.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\section on input line 5636.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=true'
(scrbook)           for `\part on input line 5645.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsection on input line 5655.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsection on input line 5655.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5665.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5665.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\paragraph on input line 5676.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\paragraph on input line 5676.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip59
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5686.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5686.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip60
\belowcaptionskip=\skip61
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box48
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lof' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6929.

\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip62
\c@figure=\count185
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lot' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6950.

\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip63
\c@table=\count186
Class scrbook Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 7123.
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(./__TexMaker/__MyStyle.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count187
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box49
)
No file Example.aux.
\openout1 = `Example.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \contentsname on input line 3.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \listfigurename on input line 3.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \listtablename on input line 3.
chapter 1.
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

LaTeX3 Info: Redefining command \BeforeClosingMainAux with sig. 'm' on line 6.

LaTeX3 Info: Redefining command \BeforeClosingMainAux with sig. 'm' on line 6.

(build/Example.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3613 strings out of 479382
 81746 string characters out of 5869369
 495749 words of memory out of 5000000
 20764 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 404623 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 106i,6n,111p,10680b,270s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/t
ype1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/typ
e1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssbx10.pfb>
Output written on build/Example.pdf (1 page, 16055 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Could you post the full log file for the example (should be called `Example.log`)?

Comment: It has nothing to do with TeXMaker. Place your package in the same folde as your document and change the path in the document and it works fine.

Comment: @HerbSchulz But I don't want to have the package in the same folder as my document... And the path seems to be correct to me.

Comment: @Marijn I added the `.log` file.

Comment: The `\usepackage` command does *not* take a path, it takes a package name. It will sometimes work with a path, but that is an accident, not by design. So put your package where TeX can find it (on a Mac, `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/...`) and then use `\usepackage{_MyStyle}`

Comment: Okay, but I have several different styles and want them to be stored in the same git repo like the content. Is there no chance to store the `.sty` file in the same directory like the content and refer to it?

Comment: What do you guys think about this variant: `\makeatletter\def\input@path{{__TexMaker/}}\makeatother` and then `\usepackage[titleStringGerman={My Title}]{__MyStyle}`

Comment: Put symbolic links in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`. I believe that will work.

Comment: Can you explain what you actually want to achieve? As @HerbSchulz says, you can create symbolic links to the relevant folders inside your local texmf folder. This is how I manage all my package code. But this is exactly the answer we gave you two years ago. :) [How to change the directory of my own .sty files in MacOS?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/438800)

Comment: Just to be clear, although the linked answer is about linking the whole `texmf` folder, the same approach can be applied to any folders within the `texmf` folder, so you can link each package to its git-controlled folder individually.

Comment: @AlanMunn Sorry, I did not explain my problem in detail. In my question two years ago, I just wanted to use TexMaker (synced on different Macs / via iCloud) to build my document. At the moment I want to use the TexMaker and Bitbucket pipeline to be able to create my document with the requirements that `__MyStyle.sty` is in the Git repo, not in the main folder but in a subfolder...

Comment: => Maybe I have to rethink about my requirements and store `__MyStyle.sty` in the main repo folder like @HerbSchulz mentioned ... Then I don't need to setup a symbolic link and it works both, at TexMaker and Bitbucket pipeline.